# for a list that doesn't contain a elements of another list

Tags: python, list, for-loop

I have two lists, I want to select all elements of the `lst1` that don't contain elements of `lst2`, the weird thing is if I do this:

```
lst1 = ['a','k','lb','o','oc']
lst2 = ['a','b','c']
for i in lst1:
    for o in lst2:
        if i.__contains__(o) == True:
            print(i)
```

I get:

```
a
lb
oc
```

which makes sense, but when I replaced `True` with `False`, instead of getting the opposite results I got this

```
lst1 = ['a','k','lb','o','oc']
lst2 = ['a','b','c']
for i in lst1:
    for o in lst2:
        if i.__contains__(o) == False:
            print(i)
```

I get

```
a
a
k
k
k
lb
lb
o
o
o
oc
oc
```

so I have two questions:

1- What happened that caused the output come out like this?

2- How can I get the elements of `lst1` that don't contain any element from `lst2` ? (output should be: `'k'`,`'o'`)

Comment: You are getting the double and triple results because you are printing the items in lst1 everytime  you get `False`, which happens more than once. You would have the same problem in the first code block if you had more than once match. For example with `lst2 = ['a','b','c', 'l']`.

Comment: Also, you really shouldn't user double-underscore functions. Just use `if o in i:`.

Comment: Why are you using `i.__contains__(o)`?? Don't do that, don't call dunder methods directly. Use `o in i`

Answer (score 2):

Python sets are a great way to solve this.  This is assuming you wanted to do this on a per-character basis.

```
lst1 = ['a','k','lb','o','oc']
lst2 = ['a','b','c']
[v for v in lst1 if not set(v) & set(lst2)]
```

The last line above is using several techniques.

**List Comprehension:** The syntax `[expression for variable in iterator if condition]` is used to generate a new list based on another iterator or list. If you include a condition it can be filtered as well.

**`set` data type**: The `set()` call constructs a new set from any iterable.  In python, strings are iterable, so it will form a set of each character in that string.  Lists are iterable so it will form a set from the items of `lst2`

**Set Intersection Operator:**  The `&` operator will intersect two sets and return a new set of only items that are in common.

**Empty set evaluates to false:** saying `not some_set` will return True only if that set is empty.

The output is:

```
['k', 'o']
```

Comment: This set solution will only check for single characters, not for substrings

Answer (score 1):

I see answers talking about list comprehension, but it looks like your case is you dont want any part of the string to match? correct me if im wrong.

In that case anyway, you'd do

```py
for i in lst1:
     found = False
     for j in lst2:
             if j in i:
                     found = True   # using bool instead of printing right away prevents dupes, since you're traversing the list over and over
     if not found:
             print(i)
```

this outputs:

```
k
o
```

otherwise you'd just use string comprehension

```py
diff = [i for i in lst1 if i not in lst2]
print(diff)
```

Comment: Do **not** use list comprehensions for side-effects

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga what do you mean by side effects?

Comment: `print` would be a side effect, a side effect is anything other than evaluating to a value. So another example of a side-effect would be `some_list.append(42)`. `.append` has a side effect

Comment: @juanpa.arrivillaga ah my bad, will fix

Answer (score 0):

1. In your original code when you change your condition to false, in the first iteration of the loop first character is picked  from lst1 which is 'a'. As 'a' does not matches with 'b' and 'c' in lst2 'a' is printed twice. Similarly, happens for remaining iterations. I will suggest using a debugger and going though each loop to understand how the value is changing might help you understand better.
2. This problem can be solved with the help of the below code where first you find all the elements that matches and then subtract it from the original list

> ```
> lst1 = ['a', 'k', 'lb', 'o', 'oc']
> lst2 = ['a', 'b', 'c']
> tmplist = []
>
> #find the list of elements that exists in lst2 from lst1
> for i in lst1:
>     for o in lst2:
>         if o in i:
>             tmplist.append(i)
>
> #removing removing tmplist elemnts from lst1
> l2 = list(list(set(lst1) - set(tmplist)) + list(set(tmplist) - set(lst1)))
> print(l2)
>
> Output:
> ['o', 'k']
> ```